# How to programmatically drag new rows - running total?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have the first few rows of my mortgage payments set up, and I want to know how to programmatically print the rest of the rows, as opposed to dragging the little corner box to output the rows.

This is important so that I can adjust the payment period, and automatically allow the total number of rows to change.

I think I have to use Array Formulas, but not sure how to print the next row the way dragging it or copy-pasting it would.

Also, I don't know how to give that array formula and ending condition.

Help?

[image]

The printing of new rows should only stop if the remaining principal gets to or below 0.

Sheet: https://drive.google.com/open?id=17Vl2M1d6gwaqHcuO_9c7SpQ-icQxUayqaLYxnur-CuU

Comment: There you go... sheet 2

Comment: Updated link...

Comment: I updated the link.

Comment: How about now? ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
={"Remaining Principal"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(LEN(E7:E), MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(E8:E)<=
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(E8:E)))*{B4; -1*INDIRECT("E"&ROW(E8)&":E"&ROWS(E:E)-1)}), 
 SIGN(E8:E)^0), ), "offset 1", -1))}
```

[image: 0]

### **[demo spreadsheet of running total](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1815RkMet1Uxx65VZAe3zO_1o1fCZcD6ruLylEhjQwiU/edit#gid=449373606&range=F7)**

---

### alternative: https://wamoyo.github.io/amortization/

Comment: Hmm... doesn't seem to work on the demo sheet. Perhaps I miscommunicated?

Comment: I adjusted the sheet I shared and dragged down to show the output I need.

Comment: I need it to print all those rows until it gets to remaining principal of 0, and then to stop printing more rows.

Comment: it does exactly that. see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1815RkMet1Uxx65VZAe3zO_1o1fCZcD6ruLylEhjQwiU/edit#gid=501905087&range=G7

Comment: You rock! Was looking at the wrong sheet.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It first said it can't overwrite F8. Then I noticed there are a bunch of extra zeros at the end. I can't tell what that formula depends on.

Comment: those zeros are from your formulas. this is arrayformula which means it needs to roll out, eg. it cant roll out if there is no space to roll out so go to your spreadsheet select range F7:F and delete it whole. then paste my formula in F7

Comment: Tried. Still doesn't work. The zeros are in your sheet row 368 and down.

Comment: the issue here is that array formula is dependant on column E but column E is dependant on column F and this creates a loop

Comment: Yup, I came across that dependency myself earlier. It might be possible to push the dependency one row up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95514/discussion-between-user0-and-costa).